# multiple iam users in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloud, amazon-iam

iam trying to create multiple iam users and apply a policy but its giving me a error, are you able to help with this one

I created a variable file that lists the users that needs to be created.

The error i am getting is

> Error: Missing resource instance key │ │   on multiple-iam-users.tf
> line 12, in resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "dev-ec2-read": │
> 12:    name       = aws_iam_user.users.name │ │ Because
> aws_iam_user.users has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on
> specific instances.      │ │ For example, to correlate with indices of
> a referring resource, use: │     aws_iam_user.users[count.index]

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "users" {
     name = var.developers[count.index]
     count = length(var.developers)
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "dev-read" {
    name = "DevUsers"
    policy = file("developer-policy.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "dev-ec2-read" {
   name       = aws_iam_user.users.name
   policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.dev-read.arn
}
```

```
variable "developers" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["james","michael","tony"]
}
```

I have a separate JSON file with just a EC2 read only policy

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `aws_iam_user` uses `count`, you have to access individual instances of your `aws_iam_user`. You can do this with `count` again:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "dev-ec2-read" {
   count      = length(var.developers)
   name       = aws_iam_user.users[count.index].name
   policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.dev-read.arn
}
```